# Trouble understanding quantum mechanical picture of atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics

This year in college we"ve had a lot of quantum stuff thrown at us, and we"ve only been doing classical mechanics till last year. We"ve been introduced to Schrodinger"s equation, electron waves, what have you. This is my understanding(rather rudimentary) so far. When you solve Schrodinger"s equation for an atom, you get a set of wave functions(what are the inputs and outputs exactly in this function?). Each wave function can describe a maximum of 2 electrons.  It was stated in one place that the wave function represents the amplitude of the electron wave, and its square gives the probability of finding the electron at a place.An orbital is a surface diagram that includes the regions where the electron described by a particular wave function is most likely to be found within the surface.
NOTE: I know the basic quantum formulae even though I may not understand what they mean.

Is my understanding right?(I realize I had forgotten to put this sentence when I first posted the question, and it would"ve seemed rather confusing as to what it was I actually wanted to know.)

Comment: Could anyone suggest an edit?

Comment: @ user42991 "Is my understanding right?" No matter how many electrons are in an atom, there is one Hamiltonian and one wavefunction, which is a function of n electron position vectors. When you solve the Schrodinger eq. for the H (or He+, Li2+ ...) atom, there is one electron and an exact solution.  For atoms with n>1 electrons, there are electron-electron repulsion terms in the Hamiltonian preventing exact solution.  An APPROXIMATION is made that the wavefunction can be written as a product of n hydrogen-like ORBITALS.  Only 2 electrons can occupy each orbital. (continued below)

Comment: (continued from abvoe) For the wavefunction of a multi-electron atom, the wavefunction must be antisymmetric with respect to the exchange of any two electrons.